# Shortcut to change screen resolution in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I need to change my screen resolution between 1366x768 and 1440x900 frequently. Is there any shortcut doing this? Like batch script, power shell script, or small program? I'd like to click a button to toggle 2 resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could use HotKey Resolution Changer. It runs in your tray and allows you to setup hotkeys as well. You can download it at http://funk.eu/hrc/. A nice introduction/tutorial can be found at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17604/change-desktop-resolution-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/.

There are a few other tools out there that do the same thing, but this one looked the most straightforward and easy to use. I hope this helps.